# Center div in bootstrap div horizontally and vertically(ASP.NET)

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have div with bootstrap class
Here is code

```
  <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div style="text-align: center; width: 50%; font-size: 20px; display: inline-block; position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;bottom: 0;right: 0;margin: auto;">
                        <p>
                            The latest offered radiology management systems are capable of helping the radiologists to provide exacting digital images and data. Viewing different types of images from various examinations is very convenient with this particular software. Through multiple viewing processes, it is possible to view the images while other people are seeing them. Viewing the imagery is satisfying because of the impressive features of the software.
                        </p>
                    </div>
               </div>
```

I need to center this div vertically and horizontally

```
<div style="text-align: center; width: 50%; font-size: 20px; display: inline-block; position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;bottom: 0;right: 0;margin: auto;">
```

I try with this style

```
style="text-align: center; width: 50%; font-size: 20px; display: inline-block; position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;bottom: 0;right: 0;margin: auto;"
```

But it not centering vertically, only horizontally.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this code a try:

```
 <div class="col-lg-12">
  <div style="text-align: center;min-width: 50%;max-width:100%; font-size: 20px; display: inline-block; top: 0;left: 0;bottom: 0;right: 0;position: absolute;margin:30%;">
   <p>
    The latest offered radiology management systems are capable of helping the radiologists to provide exacting digital images and data. Viewing different types of images from various examinations is very convenient with this particular software. Through multiple viewing processes, it is possible to view the images while other people are seeing them. Viewing the imagery is satisfying because of the impressive features of the software.
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
        <div style="text-align: center;min-width: 50%;max-width:100%; font-size: 20px; display: inline-block; top: 0;left: 0;bottom: 0;right: 0;position: absolute; margin-top:20%; margin-bottom:20% ">
           <p>
                The latest offered radiology management systems are capable of helping the radiologists to provide exacting digital images and data. Viewing different types of images from various examinations is very convenient with this particular software. Through multiple viewing processes, it is possible to view the images while other people are seeing them. Viewing the imagery is satisfying because of the impressive features of the software.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```